# using org-preview-latex-fragment to display math formula in markdown-mode emacs

Tags: emacs, latex, markdown, org-mode

I'm using emacs to edit markdown file and I wanna display the inline formulas in the markdown mode. I thought `org-preview-latex-fragment` is a good idea, but there're some problems:

1. It's slow.
2. I cannot use the `org-preview-latex-fragment` directly, I have to launch org-mode at first and until then the `org-preview-latex-fragment` can be seen and used.
3. The effect of `org-preview-latex-fragment` is whole buffer. Sometimes I just want to display the formula at a single point.
4. And When I'm using `org-preview-latex-fragment` in markdown-mode, I cannot cancel the preview anyhow.

Is there a workaround or enhancement? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about 1, 2 and 4. But for your third question:

If you place your cursor within a LaTeX fragment C-c C-x C-l org-mode will preview just that equation. If you move your cursor to a text area, it will preview the entire buffer.

You can read more about this is the [documentation](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-latex-preview.html).